# C compiler in command prompt

Tags: c

It is my understanding that the Windows operating system (Windows 7 to be exact) must come with a C compiler because the OS is written in C.

How can I access such a compiler to compile my C source code?

Comment: It doesn't come with one. You'll have to download a suitable compiler.

Comment: WHAAAT?? Then how does the C based OS work if it can't even compile its own code?

Comment: er, you compile, build & ship the executable files. Much like how most closed source software is distributed.

Comment: Windows doesn't come with its own code either.

Comment: What Sathya says is correct (at least for the versions of Windows I'm familiar with).  Compiled code does not need a compiler to be present to execute.  It is compiled before its put onto the disk and you only get the finished product which executes the, if you like, assembler code.

Comment: Oh My, I've been thinking about it wrong all this time! Thank you all for this.

Comment: Okay, if there isn't a C compiler, there must be an assembly code compiler, right? So what's the command for the x86 compiler?

Comment: No, it doesn't need an assembler either. It's all precompiled machine code binaries. The actual numeric opcodes that are directly executed by the CPU.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not necessarily - You'd just need the necessary libraries - like libc or mscrt if they are dynamically linked, or just suitable runtime support for the binaries you are running . Even many linux distributions do not come with compilers built in (I often end up installing build-essential for Ubuntu when I need to compile packages for example), so expecting windows to have one built in is not correct.

You can run compiled files without a compiler on the system. Its interpreted languages that often need the language tools installed to run - like Java or Python

If you *must* have a compiler, there's two fairly common options - the open source [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) or [microsoft's visual studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/) - there's a free version called [visual studio express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx). Install and configure one and carry one.

Comment: There are others, of course, like [OpenWatcom](http://openwatcom.com).  There's probably a "What C/C++ compilers are available for Windows?" question somewhere.